# Solve with Reals gives different answer

Tags: equation-solving

I'm very new to Mathematica (started using ver 10.4) and I was just verifying my calculations.

I have the following equation:

```
Simplify[Solve[Tan[π/4] + Tan[kx L + π/4] == 0, {kx}]]
```

That yields the same answer from pen and paper (all real values, i.e. `L ∈ Reals`):

```
{{kx -> ConditionalExpression[(π (-1 + 2 C[1]))/(2 L), C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
```

But when I try it with `Reals`:

```
Simplify[Solve[Tan[π/4] + Tan[kx L + π/4] == 0, {kx}, Reals]]
```

I get:

```
{{kx -> ConditionalExpression[-((π - 8 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] - 8 π C[1])/(4 L)), C[1] ∈ Integers]},
 {kx ->ConditionalExpression[-((π - 8 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] - 8 π C[1])/(4 L)), C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
```

Which I don't know where he got it from. Reading `Solve[]` help page, it seems `Reals` restricts all constants and functions to be real which is true for the initial case.

What is going on in the `Reals` case?

It seems that

```
8 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] = 3*π
```

So the final solution is different in the `Reals` case (`C[1]` becomes `2*C[1]` which misses some solutions compared to the first `Solve` answer).

Comment: It appears to me `8 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]` is equal to `-π`, and `8 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]]` is equal to `3*π`. In that case, I think that the two solutions with `Reals` combine to be the same as the one solution *without* `Reals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions are actually the same. Note that

```
8 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] + π // N // Chop
8 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] - 3 π // N // Chop
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
```

Therefore, the second set of solutions reduces to

```
sols = Simplify[Solve[Tan[π/4] + Tan[kx L + π/4] == 0, {kx}, Reals]] 
sols = sols/. {ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] -> -π/8, ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] -> (3 π)/8} // Expand
(* {{kx -> ConditionalExpression[-(π/(2 L)) + (2 π C[1])/L, C[1] ∈ Integers]},
    {kx -> ConditionalExpression[π/(2 L) + (2 π C[1])/L, C[1] ∈ Integers]}} *)
```

These two solutions can be rewritten as

```
(π (-1 + 4 C[1]))/(2 L)
(π (1 + 4 C[1]))/(2 L)
```

and it is relatively straight-forward to show that these two combined yield the same solutions as

```
(π (-1 + 2 C[1]))/(2 L)
```

if `C[1]` is allowed to be any integer. For instance,

```
Table[-(π/(2 L)) + (π x)/L, {x, -2, 3}] === Flatten@Table[{-(π/(2 L)) + (2 π x)/L, π/(2 L) + (2 π x)/L}, {x, -1, 1}]
(* True *)
```